# mapbox webgl transform instabilities at high zoom levels

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

When zooming into the map, typically level 16 and above, vertex positions tend to jump around. This can be seen on the mapbox demo: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/custom-style-layer/. However, there is an absence of this when using the GeoJSON LineStrings sample (https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-line/).

Are there any work arounds for this?

Comment: What do you mean, "vertex positions tend to jump around"?

Comment: I mean this https://youtu.be/4VzoMxAe57c

Comment: Whoa, that's crazy. Looks like a bug you should report here: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues

Comment: Thanks for the advice Steve, I've logged it as a bug and will report back later.